# Does grill direction and type make a big difference to CFM and noise on a return grill?

Tags: hvac

I currently have a 14x20 grill that looks like the picture below.  I'm thinking of replacing it since I can see straight into the shaft from eye level and it points inwards towards the main living room.

I'm contemplating switching it with ones that angle the blades down so that I don't see the shaft, like the item in the second picture.  Does the type of blades and angle have a big effect on the CFM and noise of the return (mine is a bit undersized).

[image]
[image]

Comment: If your current vent location is near(ish) a corner, simply remove the grate from the wall, rotate it 180° so the fins point the other direction, and you won't be able to see into the duct anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

Flow rate (CFM + noise) depends on grill area (and to a lesser extent, the number of turns the vent takes, the power of the intake fan, etc... all of which are beyond the scope of this question and answer).

The direction of the fins on an air return is aesthetic preference, most people prefer the fins to face away from normal viewing angles so you won't often see inside. Grills placed low on the wall face downward, grills placed high on the wall face upward.

Comment: Upvoted as this is generally accurate. However there is a slight tweak in that there can be a few percent difference between fin designs for CFM at a given pressure / pressure at a given CFM. If this were for a recording studio, details like this would matter. For a house your answer is totally accurate.

Comment: Technically, it's not just grill area, but grill *open* area.

Answer (score 2):

If the (new) grill is undersized you may get excessive noise and even resonant howling due to the constricted flow.

You can prevent this by offsetting the grill from the wall: in stead of installing it flush against the wall, install some 1/2in or 3/4in thick trim wood strips around 2 or 3 of the 4 sides of the opening, and fasten the grill to the trim. You can also replace the existing grill with a larger one, and use the trim to increase both the offset and perimeter.

Not all noise in the return duct is preventable by different grilling. And depending on your listening location, your noise may be dominated by air exhaust flow, not return intake.

Comment: The noise has been pretty good so far... the return duct has interior insulation as well